# Trouble sending data from Android to Arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, arduino, bluetooth

I'm trying to set up a system where an android app connects to Arduino via Bluetooth and tells it to either turn on or off its LED. I've looked through a lot of pages and source code and saw many people did it as I did but somehow my code isn't working and I cannot determine why.

Here's the entirety of my Arduino code, really simple and short.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 

SoftwareSerial Blue(0,1); // rx tx 

int LED = 13; // Led connected
char data;

char state = 0;


void setup()
{
pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
Serial.begin(9600);
Blue.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
  while(Blue.available()==0);
  if(Blue.available()>0){    // read from android via bluetooth
    data = Blue.read();
    Serial.println(data);
  } 



if (data == '1') // If data is 1, turn ON the LED
{

  digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
  Serial.println("LED ON ");
  }

if( data == '2') // if data is 2, turn OFF the LED
  {
  digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
  Serial.println("LED OFF");
  }
}
```

And here's a snippet of my android code that sends data to Arduino to control LED

```
switchLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // button that will switch LED on and off
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Attempting to send data");
                if (mmSocket.isConnected() && btt != null) { //if we have connection to the bluetoothmodule
                    if (!lightflag) {
                        try{
                            mmSocket.getOutputStream().write("1".toString().getBytes());
                            showToast("on");
                        }catch (IOException e) {
                            showToast("Error");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }


                        //btt.write(sendtxt.getBytes());
                        lightflag = true;

                    } else {
                        try{
                            mmSocket.getOutputStream().write("2".toString().getBytes());
                            showToast("off");
                        }catch (IOException e) {
                            showToast("Error");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        //btt.write(sendtxt.getBytes());
                        lightflag = false;

                    }
                } 
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the part of the code that connects to Arduino Bluetooth module. Again, fairly simple stuff and its only purpose are to connect to the module.

```
BluetoothAdapter bta;                 //bluetooth stuff
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;             //bluetooth stuff
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;             //bluetooth stuff

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Creating listeners");
        final TextView response = findViewById(R.id.response);
        Button switchLight = findViewById(R.id.switchlight);
        Button connectBT = findViewById(R.id.connectBT);

        connectBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
                mmDevice = bta.getRemoteDevice(MODULE_MAC);
                Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Attempting to send data");

                try {
                    tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                    mmSocket = tmp;
                    mmSocket.connect();
                    Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]","Connected to: "+mmDevice.getName());
                    showToast("Connected to: " + mmDevice.getName());
                }catch(IOException e){
                    try {mmSocket.close();
                    }catch(IOException c){return;}
                }
            }
        });
```

When I connect my android to the Arduino and track the serial monitor on Arduino IDE, instead of reading either 1 or 2, it reads something that looks like this:

[image]

This is produced using the Serial. println function in my Arduino code and I'm pretty sure it should display 1 or 2 but as you can see it does not. I've tried multiple workarounds like declaring it as int or char etc. If you can pinpoint any issue I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: What about android logs? Is it connected successfully?

Comment: Yes, when I check the logs, I do see the log from the Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]","Connected to: "+mmDevice.getName()); command which leads me to believe that it successfully connected

Comment: Do rx/tx leds blink when you turn on or off?

Comment: Make sure rx->tx and tx->rx

Comment: Yeah, the rx tx thing is plugged right. Im not sure what you mean by rx/tx leds though. They dont have any leds on the pins

Comment: If you're using uno or mega there're two leds located side by side on the board with text tx and rx on each led. http://www.ladyada.net/images/arduino/rxtxled.jpg

Comment: if you declare `int data; ` or you use `Serial.println((int)data, HEX);` your strange characters should reveal more info, or the baud rate does not fit. Does `Serial.println("Test");` succeed at all?
`

Comment: The TX led lights on but not RX. I am only sending data from android to arduino. Is that right? Also, Serial.println((int)data, HEX) does FFFFFFFF which is what I get when I use int data(I get 255)